# Show that $V_{n}$ is monotonically increasing and convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

As infos I have $U_{n}$ a sequence monotonically increasing and increased

$V_{n} = \frac{U_{1}+U_{2}+U_{3}+...+U_{n} }{n}$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

the objectif is to show that $V_{n}$ is monotonically increasing and convergent

I showed that since $U_{n}$ is monotonically increasing and increased then it is convergent which means $\lim n \to \infty  (U_{n})= l_{1}$

which means again $\lim n \to \infty  (S_{n})= l_{2}
$ 
then $\lim n \to \infty  (V_{n})=\lim n \to \infty \frac{l_{2}}{n}=0
$
which means $V_{n}$ is convergent but im stuck at the part of showing that $V_{n}$ is monotonically increasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that it is increasing , use the fact that 
$U_n$ is increasing , therefore $U_n\geq U_k$ with $k \in {1,..,n}$

$$nV_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{U_k}\leq nU_n$$

One can write $$(n+1)V_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{U_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{U_k}+U_{n+1}=nV_n+U_{n+1}$$

or
$$n(V_{n+1}-V_n)=U_{n+1}-V_{n+1}\geq0$$

Hence, $V_n$ is increasing

Comment: can you explicit this one $(n+1)V_{n+1}=nV_n+U_{n+1}$ didnt get the steps

Comment: I edited the answer, I added an intermediate line

Comment: Look at my first equation

Comment: fair enough .. good job man thank you